# Sum up multiple columns and select one column values by name in R

Tags: r

Given a dataframe `df` as follows, I want to sum up columns `SAT.verbal`, `SAT.math` and `SAT.prct` as `SAT.total` then filter out it:

```
           EduExp  PTR Salary SAT.verbal SAT.math SAT.prct
Alabama     4.405 17.2 31.144        491      538        8
Alaska      8.963 17.6 47.951        445      489       47
Arizona     4.778 19.3 32.175        448      496       27
Arkansas    4.459 17.1 28.934        482      523        6
California  4.992 24.0 41.078        417      485       45
Colorado    5.443 18.4 34.571        462      518       29
```

I have used `df[, (colnames(df) == "SAT.total")]`, but it gives me the following result:

```
Alabama       
Alaska        
Arizona       
Arkansas      
California    
Colorado      
Connecticut   
Delaware      
Florida       
Georgia       
Hawaii        
Idaho         
Illinois      
Indiana       
Iowa          
Kansas        
Kentucky      
Louisiana
...
```

I also tried with `df$SAT.total`, it raises an error: `Error in df$SAT.total : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`.

I'm new in R, someone could help this issue? Thanks.

UPDATE:

```
str(df)
```

Out:

```
 num [1:50, 1:6] 4.41 8.96 4.78 4.46 4.99 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:50] "Alabama" "Alaska" "Arizona" "Arkansas" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:6] "EduExp" "PTR" "Salary" "SAT.verbal" ...

summary(df)
```

Out:

```
     EduExp           PTR            Salary        SAT.verbal       SAT.math        SAT.prct    
 Min.   :3.656   Min.   :13.80   Min.   :25.99   Min.   :401.0   Min.   :443.0   Min.   : 4.00  
 1st Qu.:4.882   1st Qu.:15.22   1st Qu.:30.98   1st Qu.:427.2   1st Qu.:474.8   1st Qu.: 9.00  
 Median :5.768   Median :16.60   Median :33.29   Median :448.0   Median :497.5   Median :28.00  
 Mean   :5.905   Mean   :16.86   Mean   :34.83   Mean   :457.1   Mean   :508.8   Mean   :35.24  
 3rd Qu.:6.434   3rd Qu.:17.57   3rd Qu.:38.55   3rd Qu.:490.2   3rd Qu.:539.5   3rd Qu.:63.00  
 Max.   :9.774   Max.   :24.30   Max.   :50.05   Max.   :516.0   Max.   :592.0   Max.   :81.00
```

Comment: Where is sat total in your df?

Comment: Do you mean verbal + math + perc is total? And you want a vector of the totals?

Comment: `SAT.total <- df$SAT.verbal + df$SAT.math + df$SAT.perc` might be the solution- can post as an answer with detailed explanation if confirmed what you are after

Comment: Sorry, I get an `Error in df$SAT.verbal : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors` when sum them up.

Comment: You need `SAT.total` in `df` to filter it.

Comment: is `df` the name of your dataframe?

Comment: Sorry, my mistakes.

Comment: I use `X` as name of current data, but all were replaced.

Comment: Could we have a `str(df)` output ?

Comment: Ok, if you take the code I showed above and change the `df`s to the name of your dataframe does it give you what you want? And do you want that vector in your dataframe? I cam give a detailed explanation of it in answer if you make clear what you want

Comment: Based on the result of `str(df)`, this is not a data.frame. Use `df <- data.frame(df)` then you can use `df$SAT.total <- df$SAT.verbal + df$SAT.math + df$SAT.perc`. I'll make an ansewr out of this, you can accept it if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `df` objet is not a `data.frame` object. First, coerce it to one and then compute the `SAT.Total` with :

```
df <- data.frame(df) 
df$SAT.total <- df$SAT.verbal + df$SAT.math + df$SAT.perc
```

You can then acess it as you tried, via `df$SAT.Total` or `df[,colnames(df) = SAT.Total]`, or directly by `df[,'SAT.Total']`